# How to make vi work in single-user-mode?

Tags: shell, terminal, vi

When booting FreeBSD (I use 8.4-amd64) in single-user mode, mounting root filesystem in read/write mode and trying to `vi` some text file, I get all of this file's contents in one line. This makes `vi` unable to edit text configs.

[image]
[image]

When running multi-user, all works OK.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because not all config files are read during boot in single-user mode.

In this particular case the problem is in the `TERM` environment variable not being set properly. To fix this, just type

```
export TERM=xterm
```

and `vi` will work fine until you reboot again.

Comment: Colleagues also say they encountered cases with FreeBSD 8.4 when setting `TERM=xterm` didn't helped to solve the problem, but setting `TERM=vt100` did.

Comment: `vt220` should work as well.